# Show personalized ads outside Europe and non-personalized ads in Europe using Google Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense, gdpr, advertising

Since my website has only a cookie acceptance message, I can not show personalized ads in the European Economic Area (EEA).  Is it possible to show non-personalized Ads only in EEA?